# Average of a query column put into a Text Box

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I want to put an average of my query's column into a text box. The intent is to find the average of the marks a student has and put it into a text box in the form. The code I've put in the Control Source field so far looks like this:

```
= Avg(SELECT Marks.Mark
FROM Marks
WHERE ([IdS]=[Marks].[IdS]))
```

Where `[IdS]` is a text box with student ID of the selected student in this form. When I go back to the form view the text box gives me `#Error`.

Any idea?

Comment: `SELECT AVG(Marks.Mark) FROM ...`

Comment: @BJones now it says #Name?
=(SELECT Avg(Marks.Mark)
FROM Marks
WHERE ([IdS]=[Marks].[IdS]))

Comment: Can't reference table or query like that in textbox expression. Use DAvg() domain aggregate or a simple aggregate `=Avg([Mark])` - for the latter, apply filter criteria to form to limit the calc to single IdS. Aggregate calcs are best done in report that uses Sorting & Grouping features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a SQL statement for a control record source, or you need to use the query as the underlying form source or use a domain aggregate to get the desired result`=DAvg("[Marks]![Mark]","Marks"," [Marks]![ID] =  [IdS] ")`. (Don't forget to set a form requery when changing the [IdS] value)